# Extract values from JSON string c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, json

I used JSON.stringify to 
I have the following json string returned from javascript into a C# function:

```
"{
    \"code\":\"OK\",
    \"data\":[
        [\"adidas\",167],
        [\"adidas men's summer run basketball shoe\",35],
        [\"adidas shoes\",12],
        [\"adidas stan smith men\",9],
        [\"adidas golf shoes\",9],
        [\"adidas clothing\",9],
        [\"adidas zxz nylon man shoes\",8],
        [\"adidas uk\",8],
        [\"adidas predator\",8],
        [\"adidas perfume\",8],
        [\"adidas basketball shoes\",8],
        [\"puma and adidas shoes\",7],
        [\"mi adidas\",7],
        [\"mens discontinued adidas sandals\",7],
        [\"climate cool mens discontinued adidas sandals\",7],
        [\"china olympic adidas\",7],
        [\"china olimpic adidas\",7],
        [\"chaussure de foot adidas\",7],
        [\"alex white adidas\",7],
        [\"adidas superstars\",7]
]}"
```

Inside of the 'data' object sits an array of string & int values. I want to just get the string values out of the data arrayand into a List. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c)

Comment: Not sure how this would be a dupe since I have an anonymous json object...

Comment: Would this be in Silverlight, as it would seem from your other recent questions?

Comment: Yup, but as in some of the other ones, I didn't realize that silverlight would have so much impact on things like this - I'm just working in C#, you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not buried in the comments:

In my JS, I ended up just looping through my data object:

```
for(i=0;i<r['data'].length,i++) {
    newObject[i] = r['data'][i][0];
}
return JSON.stringify(newObject);
```

I then used JObject & JArray from the JSON.Net/newtonsoft library. Finally, I looped through my JArray to create an ObservableCollection that I bound to my ListBox ItemsSource.

Scott

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject= serializer.Deserialize(json_object);
```

You can look here for more information:

[JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

Answer (score 1):

parse it into a dictionary using something like 
[Newtonsoft](http://james.newtonking.com/).
Once deserilized ,loop the way you want.

After the comment in the above question,dictionary might have to be replaced by a data structure where your duplicates are allowed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927589/stroring-duplicate-key-value-pair-c  may be this will help you out !!

Comment: Yeah I've tried returning just the data portion of the json string going with something like `Dictionary<string, int> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(result);` (or KeyValuePair) but it just says "Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]'.", and I'm not sure where to go :(

Comment: may be just making a array of a custom object which has string and integer as its fields(just a thought).

Comment: I ended up just looping through the data object and returning an array of just strings, and using jObject and JArray to turn into a list<string>