# How do I grab entries with common values for one element from a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary

Say I have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` object with the following entries representing dogs' names and the different breed markers they're born with:

```
Name                BreedMarkers

Spot                PUG
Spot                PITBULL
Spot                BASSETT
Rover               DACHSHUND
Meat                PUG
Meat                ROTTWEILER
```

I want to grab only the pairs of strings that share common `BreedMarkers`. For example, since `Spot` and `Meat` have markers for `PUG` in common, I want to pare down the dictionary so that anything other than these pairs are removed. The end result should be:

```
Name (Key)          BreedMarkers (Value)

Spot                PUG
Meat                PUG
```

So far I've tried outputting the elements to separate `List<string>` objects, then tried a `join` between them, but this is [code smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and am hoping there's a more elegant way.

Comment: how can you have duplicate keys in Dictionary ?

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: how can you have duplicate key's in a `Dictionary`??? What's the point of using the Dictionary then?

Comment: @JonHanna I was asking in context of this question.

Comment: Sorry all, my bad, I've edited accordingly in the context of a string array instead of a Dictionary.

Comment: ...You have a string array with "Spot <spaces> PUG"? (i.e. what exactly are the `String` values in the array?

Comment: @Mayank sorry, I thought you were responding to Habib.

Comment: @crashmstr I'm glad it's Friday. Let's say instead this is a hashtable-like object that corresponds to a table with two columns, `Name` and `BreedMarker`, and has multiple entries as described above. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: "Let's say instead this is a hashtable-like object that corresponds to a table with two columns, Name and BreedMarker"? Which hashtable-like object? The best approach depends on that. (The answer given already might be such, and might not).

Comment: @JonHanna I guess it would be an object equivalent to a SQL table with two columns and no identity field similar to the structure above.

Comment: @JonHanna Actually make that a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927589/storing-duplicate-key-value-pairs-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will create a new `ILookup` (similar to `IDictionary`, but having multiple values per key) where the values become keys, and vice versa:

```
myNewDict = myOldList.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
var results = myNewDict["PUG"]; // Spot, Meat
```

Or just:

```
var results = myOldList.Where(x => x.Value == "PUG").Select(x => x.Key);
```

If you plan on doing lookups on multiple values, `ToLookup` is better; otherwise, `Where` is good.

Comment: They might well be better off using a list or tuples or pairs, or having the lookup in the opposite pattern, depending on what they're actually trying to do in general.

Comment: @Tim S. thanks for your response, but in my haste I forgot that Dictionary keys must be unique, I've edited the question more in the context of a hashtable-like object.

Comment: @Tim S. based on your suggestions I have this: `var commonMarkers = namesMarkers.ToLookup(nm => nm.Key, nm => nm.Value);` where `namesMakers` is a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. I think this will do the trick.

Comment: @DarthContinent I've updated my answer slightly. As it happens, I was using your dictionary as simply an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` which works with your `List<>`, too. I think you want to reverse your `Key`/`Value` in the lookup (like I have it), so that you're looking up by `BreedMarkers`, not `Name`.

Comment: Yeah, now the question is clearer, it's clearer this is the way to go. One might also want `.ToLookup(x => x.Value)` to keep the full pairs from the original in the lookup. (Or for the form using `Where` to omit the `Select`).